# Refering to a variable of the data frame passed in the 'data' parameter of ggplot function

Tags: r, ggplot2, scope

I would like to use a variable of the dataframe passed to the `data` parameter of function the `ggplot` in another `ggplot2` function in the same call.

For instance, in the following example I want to refer to the variable `x` in the dataframe passed to the `data` parameter in `ggplot` **in another function** `scale_x_continuous` such as in:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(2017)

samp <- sample(x = 20, size= 1000, replace = T)

ggplot(data = data.frame(x = samp), mapping = aes(x = x)) + geom_bar() +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(x), max(x)))
```

And I get the error :

```
Error in seq(min(x)) : object 'x' not found
```

which I understand. Of course I can avoid the problem by doing :

```
df <- data.frame(x = samp)
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = x)) + geom_bar() +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(df$x), max(df$x)))
```

but I don't want to be forced to define the object `df` outside the call to ggplot. I want to be able to directly refer to the variables in the dataframe I passed in `data`.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks MrFlick for this precision, and since I mostly use a unique data source, I didn't see the drawbacks you mentionned.. Do you think that it is possible to force `scale_x_continuous` to look up in the same environment as the one in ggplot call ? 

By creating helper function do you mean creating function such as in :

`helper <- function(df) {
  ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = x)) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(df$x), max(df$x)))
}`
 then call :
`helper(data.frame(x = samp)) + geom_bar() `

?

Answer (score 6):

The `scale_x_continuous` function does not evaluate it's parameters in the data environment. One reason for this is that each layer can have it's own data source so by the time you got to the scales it wouldn't be clear which data environment is the "correct" one any more.

You could write a helper function to initialize the plot with your default. For example

```
helper <- function(df, col) { 
    ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes_string(x = col)) + 
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(df[[col]]), max(df[[col]])))
}
```

and then call

```
helper(data.frame(x = samp), "x") + geom_bar()
```

Or you could write a wrapper around just the scale part. For example

```
scale_x_custom <- function(x) {
   scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(x) , max(x)))
}
```

and then you can add your custom scale to your plot

```
ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_custom(df$x)
```

Or since you just want breaks at integer values, you can calculate the breaks from the default limits without needed to actually specify the data. For example

```
scale_x_custom <- function() {
  scale_x_continuous(expand=expansion(0, .3),
    breaks = function(x) {
    seq(ceiling(min(x)), floor(max(x)))
  })
}

ggplot(data = df, mapping = aes(x = x)) + 
  geom_bar() +
  scale_x_custom()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Another less than ideal alternative would be to utilize the `.` special symbol in combination with `{}` which is imported from `magrittr`.

Enclosing the `ggplot` call in curly brackets allows one to reference `.` multiple times.

```
data.frame(x = samp) %>% 
  {ggplot(data = ., mapping = aes(x = x)) + geom_bar() +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(min(.$x), max(.$x)))}
```

[image]