# My period `.` will pipe a data frame with dplyr but not ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Pardon my (probably) incorrect terminology but I'll try my best:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% 
  count(cyl) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = .$cyl)) %>%  # line 5
  ggplot(aes(cyl, n)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, max(.$n) * 1.1)) + 
  geom_line()
```

My line 5 will properly pipe the current data frame through my syntax with `.$n`. But line # 7 won't with `.$cyl`.

I get an error *"object '.' not found"*. I tried this wrapper `{max(.$n)}` from a little searching, but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: This could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43280809/refering-to-a-variable-of-the-data-frame-passed-in-the-data-parameter-of-ggplo

Comment: What if you simply do `max(cyl)`. Is the `.` necessary?

Comment: @NelsonGon If I try `max(cyl)` I get this error _"Error in continuous_scale(c("x", "xmin", "xmax", "xend", "xintercept",  : 
  object 'cyl' not found"_.

Comment: Must be  a way through `ggplotGrob`.

Comment: Also `cyl` is a factor. Maybe you need `scale_x_discrete`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
     mtcars %>% 
          count(cyl) %>% 
          ungroup() %>% 
          mutate(cyl = factor(cyl, levels = .$cyl)) %>%  # line 5
          {
           ggplot(., aes(x = cyl, y = n, group = 1)) + 
            scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits = c(0, max(.$n) * 1.1)) + 
            geom_line()
          }
```

Comment: Can somebody (maybe Pablo?) provide a little explanation as to why the `{}` wrapper is needed, and what these `{}` are doing? Thanks